# EventReceiver: AddWebpart works only once or never.

Tags: web-part, event-receivers

I've run into an enormously frustrating problem. I want to add a Webpart to every page that's created on a certain site. I made an "Item was added to Pages library" Event Receiver, and am using the following code:

```
public class PageCreationEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        AddWikiPageWebPart(properties.ListItem);
    }

    private void AddWikiPageWebPart(SPListItem item)
    {
        SPFile file = item.File;
        SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        EditLabelsButton.EditLabelsButton wp = new EditLabelsButton.EditLabelsButton("Labels");
        wpm.AddWebPart(wp, "Side", 0);
        wpm.SaveChanges(wp);
    }
}
```

The strangest thing is that when I enter Debug mode on my test environment, the code works fine. The webpart is added to every page I create. However, when I do a regular deploy to my test environment, I first need to reboot the whole machine. Then, I only see the webpart added on the first page I create. Any page created after that doesn't have the webpart.

Deploying to my live environment, it doesn't do anything. Even after a system reset, no webpart ever shows up. I'm at a loss as to what's causing this problem.

Does anyone here have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up programmatically attaching the EventReceiver to solve this problem.
Inspiration taken from http://bramnuyts.be/2011/04/01/add-an-event-receiver-to-a-specific-list-programmatically/